# Copying SSL certificate with Ansible

Tags: docker, ssl, deployment, ansible, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to copy an SSL certificate from an Ansible host VM to a Docker host VM,and i keep having the following error

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Template source files must be utf-8 encoded"}
```

the playbook is simple and has only two steps:

```
- name: Create directory for SSL certificate
  file: path=/etc/ssl/certs/pm state=directory

- name: Copy SSL certificate from Ansible host to Docker host
  template:
    src: inventories/staging/files/pm.jks
    dest: /etc/ssl/certs/pm/pm.jks
    owner: root
    mode: 0755
  ignore_errors: true
```

When i replace pm.jks with an empty file with the same name and extension,the copying works fine,so clearly there's a problem with the format of its content. but i'm not sure how to fix this.

I'm using this command to generate the certif :

```
keytool -genkey -alias pm -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore pm.p12 -genkey -alias pm -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore pm.p12 -validity 3650
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the `file` method of Ansible instead the `template` module? The error is quite clear - you cannot use the `template` module, because the source file you are referencing is not UTF-8 encoded.

If you examine the file you created with the command you posted, you will notice that it is a **binary file:**

```
test@toor:~$ file pm.p12
pm.p12: data
test@toor:~$ less pm.p12
"pm.p12" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

Either try using a different Ansible module or try saving the file in a plain text format.

Comment: Indeed, the "template" module should only be used if you plan to replace variables in the file. This is not the case here, you don't want the file content mangled.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I stumbled over it searching for the same solution.
Here an excerpt from my playbook where I used the builtin copy module

```yaml
# playbook.yaml

- name: Create path for SSL cert
  file: path=/etc/ssl/certs/custom state=directory

- name: Copy SSL cert
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: /path/to/local/my_cert.p12
    dest: /etc/ssl/certs/custom/my_cert.p12
    owner: root
    mode: 0644
```

Rolling out on a Ubuntu VM.